# 'Open Sans' rendering differently on Chrome vs. other operating systems

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

[image: Screen shot sample]

After upgrading to 14.04, any use of the 'Open Sans' on web pages renders in Chrome using a very 'thin' (maybe the 300 weight?) version of the font which is almost unreadable on Ubuntu - however, the same rendering seems to look fine on OSX/Windows as well as Firefox on Ubuntu.  Any ideas what may have changed to cause this?

Comment: Oh good, I thought it was just me. I can confirm this on Chromium. I can also tell that for the Open Sans family, only the Light Condensed and Light Condensed variants are available (there is a separate Open Sans Condensed family that looks much better IMO).

Comment: By any chance, do you have my-weather-indicator installed?

Comment: Did you tested 12.04 or 13.10?

Comment: @Braiam: I can answer to that. I frequently visited http://qt-project.org/ in 13.10, and the website didn't appear...condensed as it does for me in 14.04. I suspect the my-weather-indicator package (available in a PPA) is the cause, as it supplies the font, which is condensed. Also, [this](http://www.pixelsinline.com/open-sans-problem-the-webfont-looks-condensed-all-of-a-sudden/) blog post suggests that the Open Sans font provided by Google is now condensed, and I suspect that's where the PPA maintainer downloaded the font from.

Comment: @saiarcot895 that sounds like an answer. Have you tried to download the old version?

Comment: @Braiam: The PPA maintainer only has one version for Trusty (coincidentally, that version is only for Trusty). Removing the my-weather-indicator package or installing Font Squirrel's Open Sans font in the `~/.fonts` folder works. I'll post this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely because you have installed the `my-weather-indicator` package, from [ppa:atareao/atareao](https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/atareao). The version of the font in this package is the same version supplied by Google Web Fonts, which now uses a more condensed version of the 400 weight (Normal). You can either

- Uninstall the `my-weather-indicator` package, or
- Download the Open Sans font from [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/open-sans), and unzip the contents into `~/.fonts` (create the folder if it doesn't exist).

Comment: This did the trick - great find.  I'll see about opening a bug report w/ the PPA maintainer, as the 400 version here looks a lot better than what the PPA was pulling in: http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans

Comment: I should mention that I sent him an email about this.

Comment: This is a per-user fix. Is there any way I can fix this as the website owner, so that Ubuntu users with my-weather-indicator would just see the uncondensed version without having to do either of the steps above?

Comment: @Martin: It should now be fixed in the package, so a user fix should be no longer necessary.

Comment: which version of the package was it fixed in (or a link to the bug would be great). I'm on 14.04 with the latest version of my-w-i but seem to still have the issue.

Comment: it seems my issue is with sans-serif now, looks different in Chrome vs. Firefox. Probably unrelated to this issue as I've removed the package. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu, "Open Sans" is just ignored by Chrome.. the font seems to be called "Sans" instead. If I add that as fallback on my site's `font-family` then I get same results as in FF/Opera etc.